# SQLite Paging issue with Offset and Limit

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am making a query like below to load 10 quotes in one page

```
arrayList.addAll(db.loadFav(CURRENT_PAGE, Constant.ITEM_PER_PAGE));
```

and `DBHelper.loadFav` is like below

```
 public ArrayList<ItemQuotes> loadFav(int offset, int limit) {
        ArrayList<ItemQuotes> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            //Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_QUOTES_FAV, columns_quotes, null, null, null, null, null);
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES_FAV + " ORDER BY " + TAG_QUOTES_ID + " ASC "+ " LIMIT " + offset+","+limit;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                Log.e("ABC", cursor.getCount() + "");
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
    
                    String qid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TAG_QUOTES_ID));
                    String quotes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TAG_QUOTES));
                    String cid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TAG_CAT_ID));
                    String cname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TAG_CAT_NAME));
                    String quote_time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TAG_QUOTE_TIME));
    
                    ItemQuotes itemQuotes = new ItemQuotes(qid, quotes, cid, cname, quote_time);
                    arrayList.add(itemQuotes);
    
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        return arrayList;
    }
```

in First Call `When CURRENT_PAGE=1, its loading 10 Quotes, WHEN CURRENT_PAGE= 2, its loading 9 Quotes and so on for next`...However I have only 11 Quotes in My Table...I don't know whats wrong with this and how I can fix it. Let me know if someone can here help me to get out of issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `CURRENT_PAGE=1` you want `OFFSET` to be `0`, when `CURRENT_PAGE=2` you want `OFFSET` to be `10` and so on.
What you are doing is that you pass `CURRENT_PAGE` to the argument `offset` of `loadFav()` and so you use `CURRENT_PAGE` as `offset`.
You should calculate `offset` as:

```
(CURRENT_PAGE - 1) * Constant.ITEM_PER_PAGE
```

So change your sql statement to this:

```
String query = 
    "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES_FAV + " ORDER BY " + TAG_QUOTES_ID + " ASC " + 
    "LIMIT " + ((offset - 1) * limit) + "," + limit;
```

But the correct thing to do is change the name of the 1st argument of `loadFav()` from `offset` to `currentPage`:

```
loadFav(int currentPage, int limit)
```

so that it is clear what that argument represents and use a variable:

```
int offset = (currentPage - 1) * limit;
```

Then you can use your sql statement as it is in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES_FAV + " ORDER BY " + TAG_QUOTES_ID + " ASC "+ " LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET "+ offset;
```

QUERY SAMPLE

```
SELECT * FROM
TABLE_QUOTES_FAV  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```